# Can't SSH (connection refused)

Tags: debian, ssh, sshd, openssh, manjaro

I'm trying to set up a headless machine running manjaro. I install and enable openssh, and can `ssh localhost`, but can't ssh by another machine. Plus, if I modify the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I cannot even `ssh localhost` anymore. I tried with Debian and it works as long as I don't modify the listening port... What in the world! Of course all ports are correctly forwarded. I'm not doing anything fancy, if I just change the port and uncomment it breaks (yes, the port I switch to is forwarded). What's going on?

Comment: is selinux activated?

Comment: Try to ssh to the machine using `ssh -vvv user@remote -p1234`  where `1234` is the default port. Don't forget to restart `sshd` after you modify the `sshd_config` file.  Also what do you mean by `forwarding` ?

Comment: Check the error logs.

Comment: No, SELinux is not active, all I did is installing openssh.

Comment: @val0x00ff it simply says "no route to host". As for the "forwarding" part, it means the ports are open both on the router and on the firewall

Comment: Can you connect to your server from the same LAN? You mention a router with port forwarding; does that mean you're trying to access your server from outside, say, a home network? If you `telnet` to port 22 (or whatever) from outside this network, do you get an ssh protocol prompt or do you get connection refused? Does your ISP block inbound connections on port 22 (or whatever)? Lots of questions - please respond to them with an [edit] to your question, ideally as if you're volunteering the information rather than replying to specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you can SSH to localhost, but you can't SSH from another machine, then either you changed the SSH configuration to forbid SSH from other machines, or there's a firewall that blocks incoming SSH connections. The firewall could be on the same machine, or on any hop between the client you're testing from and that server.

If SSH works on the default port but not after changing it to listen to another port, that means that there's a firewall that blocks the port you chose. That, or you made a mistake when changing the configuration — since you didn't post your configuration attempt, we can't help you if you made a mistake there.

Comment: As I said, the ports are forwarded correctly. I can ssh localhost only if I uninstall and reinstall openssh, but if I change sshd_config it's done, it doesn't work anymore, if I uncomment whatever line it doesn't work, I'm not tinkering with it, if I check the status of sshd.service i get red messages stating "(code=exited, status=255)" and "failed to start OpensSSH Daemon"

Comment: I tried stopping sshd.service, modifying one line of the file, then startiuthe service again, it all went good untill I changed "login grace time" to "30s" instead of "2m", then when I started the service it was broken, changing it back solves nothing, nor does modifying the file to factory values or rebooting. I don't see any pattern in this behavior. I don't know why putting a space after # worked, but it did for some time... It's surreal!